# Angular-Rxjs scan operator issue | re invoking all previously performed operations

Tags: angular, rxjs5, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I m performing crud operation on certain array in angular. I am kind of experimenting with rxjs, in order to learn it more.
It is my person facade below.

## PersonFacade.ts

```
private readonly modifyPersonSubject = new Subject<{
    person: Person;
    action: actionType;
  }>();

people$ = this.personService.getPeople().pipe(
    switchMap((initialPeople) =>
      this.modifyPersonSubject.pipe(
        // emmiting starting values
        startWith({ person: {} as Person, action: "None" as actionType }),
        scan((acc, curr) => {
          if (curr.action === "None") return acc;
          if (curr.action === "Add")
            return this.handleAddPerson(acc, curr.person);
          if (curr.action === "Delete")
            return this.handleDelete(acc, curr.person);
          if (curr.action === "Update")
            return this.handleUpdate(acc, curr.person);
          return acc;
        }, of([...initialPeople]))
      )
    )
  );

  handleAddPerson(acc: Observable<Person[]>, person: Person) {
    return this.personService.createPerson(person).pipe(
      catchError((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        return NEVER;
      }),
      switchMap((res: Person) => {
        // Update and return the accumulator with the new person
        const updatedPeople = acc.pipe(map((a) => [...a, res]));
        return updatedPeople; // Return the updated array as an observable
      })
    );
  }

// handleDelete(), handleUpdate() are kind of similar.
```

### Issue:

Initial list : ['Person1','Person2']
Whenever I am adding a person, it is working fine for first time.
Suppose I have added 'John' first (now list is ['Person1','Person2','John'])
Now, I add 'Mike' it (It is displaying ['Person1','Person2','John','Mike'] , while in the DB records are ['Person1','Person2','John','Mike','John']. If I refresh the tab, then we can see updated values from db).
Now i add the 3rd value 'Max' . Records in view are ['Person1','Person2','John','Mike','John',Max]
while in Db ['Person1','Person2','John','Mike','John',Max,Mike,John].

Similar kind of behavior happens with deleting.
Whenever i add or remove a value, all the previously performed operations are also getting invoked again.

Does someone know about it?

If I do not make http call from Scan, and accumulate the Person[] not Observable<Person[]>, then everything works fine.

```
 scan((acc, curr) => {
          if (curr.action === "None") return acc;
          if (curr.action === "Add")
             return [...acc, curr.person]
          return acc;
        }, [...initialPeople])
```

I am not able to understand, how it has cached previous operations.
I can go with ngrx/ngrx component store/ signals. But I am trying to improve rxjs skills here.
Does anyone know about it?